# complicated query need to optimize

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Below query take 116 sec to show the output.

I want to know if there is a better way to write below code:

```
select DP.PARTY_NUMBER
          ,DP.STATUS
          ,DP.PARTY_NAME
          ,DP.ATTRIBUTE14
          ,hps.party_site_number
          ,(
            select hs.party_name 
            from ar.hz_parties hs 
            where hs.party_id = hps.party_id 
            )REP_NAME,
             hps.STATUS 
from ar.hz_parties dp
    ,ar.hz_relationships rl
    ,ar.hz_party_sites hps 
where dp.party_type ='ORGANIZATION' 
and dp.status ='A' 
and dp.hq_branch_ind ='DP' 
and dp.party_id = rl.subject_id(+) 
and RL.relationship_code)'GTM_DP_OF_REP_PARTY_SITE' 
and rl.status(+) ='A' 
and rl.directional_flag(+) ='F' 
and trunc(sysdate) between trunc(rl.start_date(+)) and trunc(rl.end_date(+)) 
and rL.object_id = hps.party_site_id(+);
```

Comment: It may be you can review [this section before asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? and then to format and edit your question with the full set of information provided?

Comment: You have an error in your code:  and RL.relationship_code)'GTM_DP_OF_REP_PARTY_SITE'    it should be and RL.relationship_code = 'GTM_DP_OF_REP_PARTY_SITE'  I suppose !